# Sort the array to get nearest dates to a given date

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdate

The array is contain dictionaries as below.

```
NSArray *availableSlots = @[@{@"start" : <NSDate obj> , @"end" : <NSDate obj>},
                        @{@"start" : <NSDate obj> , @"end" : <NSDate obj>},
                        @{@"start" : <NSDate obj> , @"end" : <NSDate obj>},
                        @{@"start" : <NSDate obj> , @"end" : <NSDate obj>} ...];
```

I want to get the nearest start and end dates to a selected date.

Here is the js Pseudocode function for this solution. I want to convert it into Objective C.

```
function sortByProximityToPoint(a, b) {
        if (a.proximToPoint === undefined) {
            if (pointInTime.diff(a.start, 'minute') >= 0 &&
                pointInTime.diff(a.end, 'minute') <= 0) {
                a.proximToPoint = 0;
            } else if (pointInTime.diff(a.end, 'minute') > 0) {
                a.proximToPoint = Math.abs(pointInTime.diff(a.end, 'minute'));
            } else {
                a.proximToPoint = Math.abs(pointInTime.diff(a.start, 'minute'));
            }
        }

        if (b.proximToPoint === undefined) {
            if (pointInTime.diff(b.start, 'minute') >= 0 &&
                pointInTime.diff(b.end, 'minute') <= 0) {
                b.proximToPoint = 0;
            } else if (pointInTime.diff(b.end, 'minute') > 0) {
                b.proximToPoint = Math.abs(pointInTime.diff(b.end, 'minute'));
            } else {
                b.proximToPoint = Math.abs(pointInTime.diff(b.start, 'minute'));
            }
        }

        if (a.proximToPoint < b.proximToPoint) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.proximToPoint > b.proximToPoint) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    availableSlots.sort(sortByProximityToPoint);
```

Comment: `NSDate` provides methods for comparison and difference, and there is an abs function in (Objective-)C, what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I want to get the nearest availableSlots for the pointInTime(selected date).

Comment: Understood, and you even have some code to do it. When converting to Objective-C where did you get stuck? (You can edit the question to show this.)

Comment: Question: Can a start/end couple values be intersecting with another one? Do you need to find the start/end couple that is exactly inside a start/end couple values range? Can the start/end couple values be in past compared to the date or need to be in future? Do you really need to sort, or just find the couple values the nearest?

Comment: @Larne - good questions, however as the comparison function is supplied (just in pseudo-code) and it is sound then we don't need to ask. (The task appears to be something like finding the best available appointment time given a customers requested spot time, and it works whether there are single or multiple appointment streams [e.g. multiple doctors/hairdressers/etc.])

Comment: @CRD: It's just that even if I can understand the JavaScript pseudoCode, without comments/explaination, it takes more time, it's sometimes clearer to explains with words and examples. Especially for someone who could have the same issue, to see quickly if this fits his/here issue.

Answer (score 1):

> It's just that even if I can understand the JavaScript pseudoCode, without comments/explaination, it takes more time, it's sometimes clearer to explains with words and examples. Especially for someone who could have the same issue, to see quickly if this fits his/here issue.

So you don't understand what the algorithm does and would like an explanation in English rather than pseudo-code?

The function is a typical comparison function which returns one of three values (`-1`, `0`, `+1`) to indicate the order its two arguments are in. You see this convention in many languages, Objective-C uses symbolic names (`NSOrderedAscending` etc.) rather than numbers (but under-the-hood they are just the same three numbers).

The first two sections produce a numeric value suitable for comparison from each of the supplied argument intervals. Using `S` to mean the start time of an interval, `E` the end time, and `P` the point in time being compared against these sections handle the three cases:

```
Time ->      P          S           E
```

`P` is before the start time: return the time difference `S - P`. This is the "distance" P is from the interval.

```
Time ->      S          P           E
```

`P` is within the interval: return 0

```
Time ->      S          E           P
```

`P` is after the end time: return the time difference `P - E`. This is the "distance" P is from the interval.

Now the algorithm has two numbers to compare, with smaller meaning "better", which means comes earlier in the sort. So it compares the two numbers and returns the appropriate value indicating the order.

In Objective-C you would use a block instead of a function, passing it directly to the appropriate sort method of `NSArray`. The date-time comparison and difference functions come from `NSDate`.

While you could implement an equivalent to the Javascript caching of the "proxim" values (the `undefined` stuff in the pseudo-code) you should leave that until, and if, you find it necessary. Just use local (to the block) variables.

Note also that the use of the absolute value function is unnecessary - think about it.

HTH

Comment: It is a good explanation CRD. I finally managed to come up with the Obj-c code. Hope my answer will help for someone as well

Answer (score -1):

```
// sort them
NSArray *sortedArray = [availableSlots sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSMutableDictionary* a, NSMutableDictionary* b) {

    if (a[@"proximToPoint"] == [NSNull null]) {
        if ([(NSDate *)a[@"start"] compare:time] != NSOrderedDescending && [(NSDate *)a[@"end"] compare:time] != NSOrderedAscending) {
            [a setObject:@0 forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        } else if ([(NSDate *)a[@"end"] compare:time] == NSOrderedAscending){
            [a setObject:@(abs([(NSDate *)a[@"end"] compare:time])) forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        } else {
            [a setObject:@(abs([(NSDate *)a[@"start"] compare:time])) forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        }
    }

    if (b[@"proximToPoint"] == [NSNull null]) {
        if ([(NSDate *)b[@"start"] compare:time] != NSOrderedDescending && [(NSDate *)b[@"end"] compare:time] != NSOrderedAscending) {
            [b setObject:@0 forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        } else if ([(NSDate *)b[@"end"] compare:time] == NSOrderedAscending){
            [b setObject:@(abs([(NSDate *)b[@"end"] compare:time])) forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        } else {
            [b setObject:@(abs([(NSDate *)b[@"start"] compare:time])) forKey:@"proximToPoint"];
        }
    }

    if (a[@"proximToPoint"] > b[@"proximToPoint"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (a[@"proximToPoint"] < b[@"proximToPoint"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Sorry but this answer does not implement the algorithm and it also does not work. The `proximToPoint` value is always either `0` (point within slot) or `1` (point outside of slot). Read my explanation of the algorithm again. You've also emulated Javascript's ability to dynamically add properties by requiring all the elements to be sorted are mutable dictionaries *and* have a key `proximToPoint` with the value `[NSNull null]` before the sort starts. Your answer doesn't include the code to do this; you don't need to do this caching, but if you do can you not think of a better way?